# Bibliography does not compile - I found no \bibdata command---while reading file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, compiling, compilation-error

I worked for a while on a Latex thesis without any issue using Git to commit the changes I made across the time.

I just changed the device where I'm working on, cloning the repo and using the same configuration editor (Texstudio) and I run into this issue:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "thesis"

I couldn't open auxiliary file appendix/appendice.aux
---line 468 of file thesis.aux
 : \@input{appendix/appendice.aux
 :                               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open auxiliary file appendix/lists.aux
---line 469 of file thesis.aux
 : \@input{appendix/lists.aux
 :                           }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open auxiliary file appendix/bib.aux
---line 470 of file thesis.aux
 : \@input{appendix/bib.aux
 :                         }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open auxiliary file bu.aux
---line 471 of file thesis.aux
 : \@input{bu.aux
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux
(There were 6 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

I really don't know why it was working on one machine and not on this one, despite using the same source code, the same editor (TexStudio), same OS (Win10) and MikTeX.

This is the Chapter related to the bibliography:

```
\chapter{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\bgroup
\bibliographyunit
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{}
\renewcommand\bibname{~}
\bibliography{bib/mybib}
\egroup
\cleardoublepage
```

Some online solutions said that this problem is often related to putting two times **\end{document}**, resulting in aborting the compilation of the bibliography. But, I really checked each single .tex file and no one has \end{document} (except for the main one, of course).

Any ideas? Where can be the source of trouble?

Comment: Did you make sure to run LaTeX (that is: your favourite flavour of LaTeX, i.e. pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...) before you run BibTeX? Can check that the `.aux` files BibTeX complains about `appendix/appendice.aux`, `appendix/lists.aux`, `appendix/bib.aux`, `bu.aux` are present in/relative to your document directory?

Comment: I'm using PdfLatex and BibTex. Actually I press on "Build and View" inside TexStudio, I think it does the job but unsure if I there is a way to explictly compile it first, then run bibtex. I see in the messages that pdflatex run first, then bibtex, so it should be fine.

As for the second question, yes they are present in the correct directory.

Comment: Hrmm, if the `.aux` files are present, BibTeX should be able to find them. Can you try running BibTeX from the command line/console/terminal directly instead of having it run by your editor? (Open the command line, navigate into the correct folder using `cd`, run `bibtex thesis` [assuming your main `.tex` document is called `thesis.tex`]).

Comment: I did it and the result is: "I couldn't open file name `thesis.tex.aux'"
That's very strange! Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: That message sounds as if you ran `bibtex thesis.tex`. You need to run `bibtex thesis` or `bibtex thesis.aux`.

Comment: Oh sorry I did it, but the output is exactly the same as the one I posted in the question section. So, even after using bibtex alone the problem still remains. Could it be an hint the understand the cause?

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. If the `.aux` files are where they should be and yet BibTeX still claims it can't open them, then that doesn't sound good. (The only idea I have is that this could be a very convoluted file permission issue, but it would have to be very weird and I doubt that is the case.)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a (possibly) similar issue.

It was a document based on some really old template. Probably using some later version of the texlive distribution broke my build.

I was able to identify the culprit by stripping down the thing to a minimal example that still demonstrates the error and "fix" it by removing a `\usepackage{bibunits}` declaration.

What I should have done, is probably a proper refactoring of the document template. Throw out or replace deprecated and/or conflicting stuff. But for now this temporary "fix" seems sufficient.